# Ускорение обработки ~ 1000000 записей

Tags: база-данных, delphi, firebird, devexpress, fibplus

У меня есть форма для выбора адреса по КЛАДР. Она состоит из нескольких TcxExtLookupComboBox. В каждом TcxExtLookupComboBox отображаются данные по одному из уровней данных КЛАДРа. Если, например, мы выбрали Кировскую область, то в остальных произойдет перезагрузка данных только этой области - города, районы, улицы, все перезагрузится. Если выбрать другой регион, произойдет тоже самое.

**Задача:** Мне нужно ускорить обработку и отображение данных для выбора пользователем адреса.

**Исходные данные:**

1. Есть база данных FireBird 2.5, в которой больше 1000000 записей.
2. Для получения и отображения данных используются компоненты TpFIBDataSet [FIBPlus] и TcxExtLookupComboBox [DevExpress].
3. Сейчас работает так: есть 6 TpFIBDataSet, которые связаны между собой, и 6 TcxExtLookupComboBox, в которых отображаются данные из тех шести датасетов. Каждый раз при выборе записи в одном из датасетов, происходит перевыборка во всех подчиненных. Я хочу этого избежать, то есть уменьшить количество обращений к базе данных.

**Мое предположительное решение:** убрать связь master-detail, и использовать свойство Filtered.

**Вопрос:** Насколько вырастет или упадет производительность отображения данных? И есть ли еще какие решения?

Comment: 1. Определите на что тратится время (фильтрация в интерфейсе, фильтрация в БД, получение из БД, вывод в интерфейс). 2. Исходя из этого подумайте как это оптимизировать. Сейчас вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: @Kromster, время тратится сейчас на обращение к базе при каждом выборе в TcxExtLookupComboBox, привязанной к master датасету на клиенте, то есть получается да - выбор из БД. И вот вопрос как раз в том, поможет ли фильтрация датасета уже с данными с помощью Filtered или нет ...

Comment: Выбор из БД.. А на что тратится время, это задержки сети (БД далеко) или обработка запросов на БД (сложные правила фильтрации)? Если первое, то точно напрашивается кэширование данных на клиенте. И второй момент, опишите как идет работа, вы выбираете фильтрами что-то и показываете подходящие записи? Не получается ли, что вы впустую гоняете сотни тысяч строк пока идет настройка фильтров?

Comment: @Kromster, база находится на том же компьютере, было бы иначе обязательно бы указал) Запросы к БД примерно такие - есть процедура, и с помощью нее формируются строки, которые возвращаются из БД в датасеты, к этим датасетам привязаны компоненты TcxExtLookupComboBox, и отображают данные из датасетов, связанных master-detail. При каждом выборе значения в TcxExtLookupComboBox, который привязан к master датасету, происходит перевыборка в подчиненных датасетах и так далее. Фильтрами пока ничего не выбираю, оцениваю можно ли с помощью их ускорить работу всего процесса.

Comment: @Kromster, все строки, которые получаю, используются. Но нужно ускорить этот процесс, поэтому я спрашиваю про Filtered

Comment: Вы же не заполняете в ComboBox более пары сотен значений?

Comment: @Kromster, у меня очень много значений, так что да, загоняю, но это делается автоматически с помощью компонента cxGridViewRepository

Comment: Тогда переделывайте UI. Не нужно в комбобоксе держать значений больше, чем пользователь может адекватно увидеть и выбрать.

Comment: @Kromster, у меня это все дело - адрес, и переделывать так кардинально нельзя, задача стоит только в ускорении, это продакшн

Comment: Распишите нормально, что у вас за задача. Вам нужно выбирать адрес по КЛАДР? Комбобоксы с тыщами значений для этого - дурная затея

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74969/discussion-between-vladislav-kuznetsov-and-kromster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ускорить целую выборку так и не получилось. Как решение - делить ее на части и обрабатывать по очереди данные в них.